# Python 3 library that supports BLE central and peripheral?

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I have been working on a project lately where i am supposed to setup raspberry pi3 model b as both central and peripheral. Aim is to connect pi to peripheral(NRF module) , after a secured connection peripheral searches for a time service availble on central device(pi3) inorder to update its system time. After peripheral device syncs its time with pi3 , pi3 continues to use advertised service exposed by peripheral device. So i basically need a python3 library that can be used to achieve such a task and any documentation regarding it.

Note:I am using Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 on my raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

On linux the Bluetooth stack is [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/) which uses D-Bus to expose its API. Any programming language can access this API if it has D-Bus bindings available. For Python there are some bindings listed at https://wiki.python.org/moin/DbusExamples .

The documentation for BlueZ D-Bus API's are at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

BlueZ also have a collection of Python examples at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test

Sounds like you want to implemnt a [Current Time Service (CTS)](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/) on the Raspberry Pi which is detailed at: https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Services/org.bluetooth.service.current_time.xml

Comment: Yes indeed my plan is to implement cts on central device . Thanks for insights on bluez , but my time constraints are strictly less and it would take a lot of time with bluez . Thats why i was hoping to find a similar library like BLESuite V.2.0 which is really convenient to use , but wont work with python3 .